# What is the analog of startActivityForResult() but using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 4 tabs, each runs a fragment when selected.
From tab #2 fragment I want to start another fragment to run on tab #2 and get results from it. What is the right way to do this? Are there any examples around?

If those were activities, and not fragments, I know that I would use startActivityForResult().

Comment: You need to handle that on your own, there is no startActivityForResult() mechanism for fragments.

Comment: @Luksprog I guess you are right, see the accepted answer for a working solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a recommended pattern for fragment interaction. Each of your fragments declares the way it needs to interact with others using the interface:

here's the code for the first fragment:

```
public class Fragment1 {
    private Listener listener;

    @Override
    public void onCreateView(...) {
        Bundle args=getArguments();            
        if (args!=null) {
            Object arg=args.getParcelable("result");
            //use the result for something
        }

        //...
        someView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener!=null)
                    listener.onFragment2Requested();
            }
        });
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        this.listener=(Listener) activity;
    }

    public interface Listener {
        public void onFragment2Requested();
    }
}
```

and the second fragment:

```
public class Fragment2 {
    private Listener listener;

    @Override
    public void onCreateView(...) {
        //...
        someView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Object object=...

                if (listener!=null)
                    listener.onWorkDone(object);
            }
        });
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        //will throw ClassCastException unless your Activity
        //implements Listener interface of your fragment
        this.listener=(Listener) activity;
    }

    public interface Listener {
        public void onWorkDone(Object someResult);
        public void someOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

and then, finally, your `Activity`, which acts as the coordinator:

```
public class YourActivity extends 
                              FragmentActivity 
                          implements 
                              Fragment1.Listener, 
                              Fragment2.Listener {

    public void onFragment2Requested() {
        Fragment2 frg2=new Fragment2();
        //here goes your code to switch fragments the way you want    
    }

    public void onWorkDone(Object someResult) {
        //if you don't want to create new instance of fragment each time
        //you can try to get it from FragmentManager.
        //But don't try to store reference to it anywhere (activity field etc.)
        //it could interfere with fragment recycling mechanism
        Fragment1 frg1=new Fragment1();
        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable("result", someResult);
        //instead of arguments, you could use setter method, but that way 
        //your Object is lost when fragment is recreated upon orientation change, etc.
        frg1.setArguments(args);
        //here goes your code to switch fragments the way you want
    }

    public void someOtherMethod() {
        //...
    }
}
```

I know, this might seem too much of code, but this is the way it's done. 
Also, this pattern is covered [in this article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: I tried it and it works fine. I think the right paradigm is to create a base fragment class with two interfaces. First interface has the method `startFragmentForResult(tag,requestCode)` and the second interface has `onFragmentResult(requestCode,resultCode,data)`, and extend all fragments from it. That's my next step.